# Python: How to wait for threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I try threading in python. I have some code and hear that my program is waiting for threads if i use the .join method. But in the following code I get the print 'done' earlier then the prints in my thread. But why?

```
def getresults(seed):
  print("get results now")
  results[seed]
  i = 0
  threads = []
  for suggestengine in suggestengines.keys():
      i += 1
      t = threading.Thread(target=getSuggestengineResult, args = (suggestengine, seed, i))
      threads.append(t)
  print('threads initialized')
  for thread in threads:
      thread.start()
  for thread in threads:
      thread.join
  print('done')
```

Comment: You mean `thread.join()`, not `thread.join`. If this is really your code, then the reason is obvious: by doing `thread.join` and not `thread.join()`, you don't actually invoke the `join()` method.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan oh what a silly mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If correcting that type does in fact resolve your issue, you should probably delete this question.